# VB WebBrowser set a default page?

Tags: vb.net

I'm just starting to look at VB and thought about putting a browser together, no buttones or search bars, it should just simply open and display the given page. I can't seem to achieve this, my code may be way off.

```
Public Class Form1

Private Sub WebBrowser1_DocumentCompleted(sender As Object, e As WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventArgs) Handles WebBrowser1.DocumentCompleted
    WebBrowser1.Navigate("http://www.google.co.uk")
End Sub

End Class
```

Comment: Move the navigate statement to a button.  Click the button and the page should display.  You could also add the url to the Url property of WebBrowser1 in the designer and the page will load when the browser control is loaded.

Comment: is there no way of loading a default/home page without clicking anything?

Comment: Read the third sentence.  Remove your DocumentCompleted event handler for now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put your code in the `load` event of your form:

```
Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
    WebBrowser1.Navigate("http://www.google.co.uk")
End Sub
```

Answer (score 2):

You can set Url property of WebBrowser to display your default page.
If you don't want to allow navigation you must set AllowNavigation to False.