# Set Default homepage of any browser in vb.net window application

Tags: vb.net

I want to change the default page of any browser like(IE,firefox,crome etc) in form load event using window application pf vb.net. any one knows how to do it. thanks in advance.
give example for chrome.

Comment: check this link

This is solution of your answer
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10963271/how-to-change-home-page-in-internet-explorer-using-c?lq=1



http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17044033/vb-webbrowser-set-a-default-page

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10963271/how-to-change-home-page-in-internet-explorer-using-c?lq=1 hope this link helps

Answer (score 3):

There is no common way to set the default page for *any* installed browser. You will have to develop individual solutions for every single browser that you want to support.

Comment: @user3257024: That's a different question, so I suggest that you start a different SO question for that.

Comment: In addition this is not a tutorial site. Your new question will not be favorably received if you don't do your homework first.